# Is there a way to achieve this with groupby/pivot table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to transform this dataframe

```
Year    Gender  Count
2018    Female  4010
2018    Male    19430
2019    Female  3212
2019    Male    16138
```

To

```
Year    Male    Female    Ratio  

2018   19430    4010        0.21

2019   16138    3212        0.20
```

using groupby/pivot/any custom function????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
new_df = df.pivot("Year", "Gender", "Count").assign(Ratio=lambda r: r.Female / r.Male)

# To remove the "Gender" name from column index
new_df.columns.name = None 

# Reset row index as column
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   Year  Female   Male     Ratio
0  2018    4010  19430  0.206382
1  2019    3212  16138  0.199033
```

Comment: `df.pivot(...).assign(...).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()` if you didn't want to break the chain.

Comment: @HenryEcker Good to know the `rename_axis` trick!